# cntk tutorial outputs illegal instruction error : python FeedForwardNet.py

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk

I was not able to find any post with same error.

Platform:  Linux Mint 18.1, 64 bits, AMD CPU

Python 3.5

Here are the outputs:

~/CNTK-Samples-2-0/Tutorials/NumpyInterop $ python FeedForwardNet.py

Selected CPU as the process wide default device.

Build info:

```
Built time: May 31 2017 17:14:07
Last modified date: Thu May 18 15:42:56 2017
Build type: release
Build target: CPU-only
With 1bit-SGD: no
With ASGD: yes
Math lib: mkl
Build Branch: HEAD
Build SHA1: ade8bc05d30e61160da729aee078e22f8bd4fced
Built by Source/CNTK/buildinfo.h$$0 on a4dbcb4fb82a
Build Path: /home/philly/jenkins/workspace/CNTK-Build-Linux_2
MPI distribution: Open MPI
```

MPI version: 1.10.3

Illegal instruction

The preceding last line ("Illegal instruction") above is part of the outputs.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what goes wrong because Linux Mint is not a platform CNTK builds or tests on. My suggestion would be to use a supported platform for example via an Ubuntu docker image.